# how to validate string in NSUserdefaults

Tags: iphone

i am getting some id from the web services.

eg:101.

that id i am save in NSUserdefaults and give that value to the string.

Now i need to validate that string like if that string is equal to 0 i need to fire one action and if that value is not equal to 0 i need to fire another action.

for that my code is like this.

```
NSLog(@"id is%@",[defaults objectForKey:@"id"]);
NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [defaults objectForKey:@"id"]];

NSLog(@"string %@",intString);
if ([intString isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    NSLog(@"yes  it is 0");
}
else {
   NSLog(@"No it not eqal to zero");
}
```

for the first time in console id is 0,string is 0

And if i check second time   id is 0, string is 100243248.

i did n't get what this 100243248 value.

I need to check id in NSUserdefaults. if that value is 0 i need to fire one action and if that value is not equal to zero i need to fire another action.

how can i done can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

---

Comment: may be it is getting modified in some other places ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead: `NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"id"]];`

You're not being consistent in what you store in `NSUserDefaults`, it looks like.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think that `%d` takes the *int* value of whatever you give it. In this case you're passing an *object* to `stringWithFormat`. You should instead use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ...`.

What's actually happening here is that you're printing out the pointer value of the object returned by `objectForKey`. The first time this is nil (0), the second time you get 100243248 which is the memory address of something in memory (whatever you stored into `NSUserDefaults`).